# Working with date

Tags: javascript

I have wrote function to show range of years for registration form. It works as it shoud but I have couple of questions. 
Is it good? should I do some thing more or just correct something? 
And because I do not have experience with object oriented js how should I do this function in oop?
Function is called on body onload.
Here is the code:

```
function iYears() {
    var years = document.getElementById('sYears');
    var sDate = new Date();
    var cYear = sDate.getFullYear();
    var startYearsFrom = 1900;
    var countYrs = [];
    for (y = startYearsFrom; y <= cYear; y++) {
        countYears.push(y);
    }
    countYrs.sort(function (a, b) {
        return b - a
    });
    for (var opt in countYrs) {
        var options = countYrs[opt].toString().split();
        var selOption = document.createElement('option');
        years.options.add(selOption);
        selOption.value = options[0];
        selOption.innerHTML = options[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: This might be a question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: [Cross-posted on Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/75847/9357)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've refactored a little bit your code:

```
function iYears(target, startYearsFrom) {
    var cYear = (new Date()).getFullYear();
    for (var y = cYear; y >= startYearsFrom; y--) {
        var selOption = document.createElement('option');
        selOption.value = y;
        selOption.innerHTML = y;
        target.options.add(selOption);
    }
}

// invoke the function on a given target object
iYears(document.getElementById('sYears'), 1900);
```

1. make it reusable:
   moved the target HTML node and the start year to be arguments of the `iYears` function, this way you can reuse this function with different HTML elements and different date limits.
2. one single `for` loop:
   avoid to use many `for` loops and `sort()` where you can. here you can use a *negative `for` loop* that solves your problem.
3. prefer offline DOM manipulations:
   when you create the new option element then set all it's properties before to append it to the DOM, it's more efficient.

Here you have the fiddle for the code above:
http://jsfiddle.net/marcopeg/ta2vLxpm/

Good luck with your app!